# enum is not a non-static data member or base class of class

Tags: c++, oop, breadth-first-search, non-static

Hey i am trying to write BFS algorithm.My graph class looks like this.

```
class Graph {
    struct Vertice{
        int ID;
        int distance;
        enum color{ WHITE, GREY, BLACK };
        Vertice* parent;
        Vertice(int n) :ID(n), distance(0), color(WHITE), parent(0){};
    };

public:
    Graph(int n) : adjList(n) {

    }

    void add_edge(int u, int v) {
        adjList[u - 1].insert(adjList[u].begin(),Vertice(v));
        adjList[v - 1].insert(adjList[v - 1].begin(), Vertice(u));
    }

    vector<int> shortest_reach(int start) {

    }

    vector<list<Vertice>> adjList;
};
```

In the initializer list of the constructor for struct Vertice i get the following error 
color is not a non-static data member or base class of class Graph::Vertice.
I googled as much as i could but did not find anything similar to this.

Comment: `color` is a type name, you need to declare member fields of this type,

Answer (score 1):

```
enum color{ WHITE, GREY, BLACK };
```

This will only define the values, not as one of them being instansiated inside each `Vertice`.

Add another line to also use a value:

```
enum class Color{ WHITE, GREY, BLACK };
Color color;
Vertice* parent;
Vertice(int n) :ID(n), distance(0), color(Color::WHITE), parent(0){};
```

Answer (score 0):

In the above code snippet you are declaring the type, not a member of the `Vertice`. See the code snippet below.

```
class Graph {

    typedef enum color_t{ WHITE, GREY, BLACK } color_t; // Declare the enum type here.

    struct Vertice{
        int ID;
        int distance;
        color_t color; // the member.

        Vertice* parent;
        Vertice(int n) :ID(n), distance(0), color(WHITE), parent(0){};
    };

public:
    Graph(int n) : adjList(n) {

    }

    void add_edge(int u, int v) {
        adjList[u - 1].insert(adjList[u].begin(),Vertice(v));
        adjList[v - 1].insert(adjList[v - 1].begin(), Vertice(u));
    }

    vector<int> shortest_reach(int start) {

    }

    vector<list<Vertice>> adjList;
};
```